# How in the IntelliJ IDEA to hide path of module in the left sidebar (project structure)?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

I'm using the IntelliJ IDEA.

I do not like how it shows the long path to the modules in the left sidebar (project structure).

I honestly have climbed all the settings and I searched in google.

Does anyone know how to hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dropdown of the project tab, select "Project Files":

[image: Project Tool Window Dropdown]

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks! But the files do not open when double-clicked. When you turn off the options "Autoscroll from Source", "Autoscroll to Source" and turn on  option "Show members". I temporarily solved this by turning off option  "Show members" and moving the "Structure" panel to the right side.